# Is it possible to use css to shrink text to automatically fit the size of the div

Tags: html, css, ejs

I have been working on a project and there is one page where it would show several divs (using ejs), but if one div has 3 lines and the other has 2, one would be a lot bigger than the other.

[image]

And here is my code for the **`HTML`** / **`ejs`** file:

```
<div id = "home" class = "container">
<h1 class="polls-head">Polls</h1>
<div class="main-aligner">        
    <% for(var i = 0; i < allPolls.length; i++){ %>
    <div class="title" id="dynamicDiv">
        <div class="poll-name" id="dynamicSpan">
        <%= allPolls[i].title %>
    </div>
    <div class="poll-link">
        <div class= "poll-view">
            <a href="polls/<%= allPolls[i]._id %>" class="btn button view">View Poll</a>
        </div>
        <div class="createdBy">
            <p>Created by: <%=allPolls[i].createdBy %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <%}%>
</div>
</div>
```

And for the **`CSS`** file

```
.title
{
    font-family: "Lato";
    width: 365px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150%;
    background-color: #dfdce3;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
.poll-name
{
    font-size: 50px;   
}
```

Is it possible to shrink the size of the text automatically if it is longer than 2 lines? Or is there any way I can make all the boxes the same size so the boxes are always the same size as the box with the most lines?

Comment: This sounds like a job for JavaScript. I'm not familiar with any way to do this with CSS. You can mask the text, but to actually shrink it you will need JS.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try to use this code below

```
.poll-name {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1em; /* a */
  max-height: 2em; /* a x number of line to show (ex : 2 line)  */
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you adek herry! These lines of code worked really well with my site!

Comment: Glad to hear that, anyway you may need to check these code on cross browser.

Comment: To be clear...  That doesn't actually _shrink_ the text, right?  It just cuts off everything after _X_ lines?

Comment: I am seriously confused as to how this was chosen as the accepted answer. It does not shrink the text to fit in any way, it simply cuts off all lines after a given number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use em or rem instead of pixels to size your font. It will be responsive and change with the size of the element it is inside of.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try applying flexbox, such as display:inline-flex;

https://developer.mozilla.org/enUS/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

2. Grids could also be effective with multilines as well

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Step 1 has a broken link